# The don't-lose-your-work message displays "null" if there isn't any work

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, posting, warning

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a question
2. Type an answer
3. Delete contents of the answer
4. Click on a link such as Unanswered

**IE7/8:** The error message will read **null** instead of the normal **You have started writing or editing a post**.

**Firefox:** Nothing happens and you are taken to the link without being prompted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**This is fixed in the next push.**

I was returning `null` in the `onbeforeunload` handler instead of not returning anything, e.g.:

```
// incorrect behavior in IE
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return (hasUserEnteredText) ? "You've started writing a post!" : null;
}

// correct behavior everywhere!
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   if (hasUserEnteredText)
      return "You've started writing a post!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not getting any message box at all when I do this (Firefox 3.5.3)

**Confirmed:** I am getting it in IE7...

Comment: Same here. No repro.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be IE specific.

Comment: Surprise surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed: Windows XP in IE 7